# Sliding Menu in android

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using a sliding menu but it is working only for a device with a device higher than 3.0.
I want to run the same code using defferent versions of android . Can anyone help me to find  solution ??

Here is my code

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
      navDrawerItems.add(new   NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
navMenuIcons.recycle();
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
            R.string.app_name, 
            R.string.app_name 
    )
{
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
invalidateOptionsMenu();
 }
 public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
 getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
 invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
};
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
displayView(0);
    }
}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{
displayView(position);}
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu();
    return true;
}




private void displayView(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = BackupFragment.getInstance();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new RestoreFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        //erreur de creation de fraglent
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe some functions are only enabled for a certain versions of android, but it is only a guess 'cause you're not providing an example. Please, share some code.

Comment: I edited my post so you can now my code . It is working well in a 3.0 device'version but when I change to a lower version device it craches !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app crashes because `ActionBar` is not suported below Honeycomb (3.0).

To avoid this problem you must use the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

To have a better explanation:

```
The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

**Caution:** Be certain you import the ActionBar class (and related APIs) from the appropriate package:
```

- If supporting API levels lower than 11:

  `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`
- If supporting only API level 11 and higher:

  `import android.app.ActionBar`

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Yes that it the problem it it added in Android 3.0.

Now when I add "import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar "
I get this error:
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved

Comment: Fist of all, you must setup the support library (take a look at the link in my answer); and then you must instanciate the `ActionBar` calling `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

Comment: Make sure you have set up correctly the support library.

Comment: Have you read the link in my answer? It's everything there step-by- step.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MenuDrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) library. Works great!

Comment: Then it should not be a problem, MenuDrawer works in API 7 and up.